# Maria DB docker Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mariadb, mariadb-10.6

I'm using a MariaDB docker image and keep getting the Warning:

```
[Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

This is my docker file used to create the image:

```
FROM mariadb:10.6.4
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD pw
ENV MARIADB_DATABASE db1
ENV MARIADB_USER user1
ENV MARIADB_PASSWORD user1pw
```

I start the container in docker-compose :

```
mariadb:
    restart: always
    image: mariadb_image
    container_name: mariadb_container
    build: topcat_mariadb/.
    ports:
      - 2306:3306
```

and I access the container from another container using:

```
mysql+pymysql://user1:user1pw@mariadb_container:3306/db1
```

Most of the solutions google found was running some kind of SQL statement, but as I'm running a docker container, I need an ephemeral solution.
Anyone know how to fix this in docker?

-----EDIT-----

I had forgotten to add the health check section to the dockercompose file:

```
mariadb:
    restart: always
    image: mariadb_image
    container_name: mariadb_container
    build: topcat_mariadb/.
    ports:
      - 2306:3306  
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'mysqladmin ping']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 10
```

Comment: How are you trying to access the database? Are you running a command inside the container? On your host? How did you start the container?

Comment: Hi, i'm accessing the container from within another container. I have updated the question to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Based on the update to your question, you're trying to run the `mysqladmin ping` command inside the container. `mysqladmin` is attempting to connect as the `root` user, but authenticating to your database server requires a password.

You can provide a password to `mysqladmin` by:

- Using the `-p` command line option
- Using the `MYSQL_PWD` environment variable
- Creating a credentials file

If we move the root password out of your image, and instead set it at runtime, we can write your `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mariadb:
    restart: always
    image: mariadb_image
    container_name: mariadb_container
    build: topcat_mariadb/.
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
      - "MYSQL_PWD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'mysqladmin ping']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 10
```

And then in our `.env` file we can set:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pw1
```

Now after the container starts up we see that the container is
healthy:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS      NAMES
c1c9c9f787e6   mariadb_image    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   28 seconds ago   Up 27 seconds (healthy)   3306/tcp   mariadb_container
```

As a side note, it's not clear from this example why you're bothering to build a custom image: it's better to set the environment variables at runtime, rather than creating an image with "baked-in" credentials.

---

### Previous answer

I can't reproduce your problem when using the `mysql` client or Python code. Given the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mariadb:
    restart: always
    image: mariadb_image
    container_name: mariadb_container
    build: topcat_mariadb/.

  shell:
    image: mariadb:10.6.4
    command: sleep inf
```

(The directory `topcat_mariadb` contains the `Dockerfile` from your
question.)

If I exec into the `shell` container:

```
docker-compose exec shell bash
```

And run `mysql` like this:

```
mysql -h mariadb_container -u user1 -p db1
```

It works just fine:

```
root@4fad8e8435df:/# mysql -h mariadb_container -u user1 -p db1
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 6
Server version: 10.6.4-MariaDB-1:10.6.4+maria~focal mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [db1]>
```

It looks like you may be using sqlalchemy. If I add a Python container
to the mix:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mariadb:
    restart: always
    image: mariadb_image
    container_name: mariadb_container
    build: topcat_mariadb/.

  shell:
    image: mariadb:10.6.4
    command: sleep inf

  python:
    image: python:3.9
    command: sleep inf
```

And then run the following Python code in the `python` container:

```
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> e = sqlalchemy.engine.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user1:user1pw@mariadb_container:3306/db1')
>>> res = e.execute('select 1')
>>> res.fetchall()
[(1,)]
```

It also seems to work without a problem.

Comment: Many thanks for this, I appreciate your effort. There must be something else trying to access it. I shall revisit the system and report back.

Comment: ah ok, i had forgotten to add the health check section to the docker-compose file, the test part is set to `test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'mysqladmin ping']` which seems to be causing it

Comment: sorry about that, have edited the question

Comment: I've updated my answer. This is why we ask for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :).